# Two dimension array and enum

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, enums

This is a evaluation function for Tic Tac Toe.  There is a error around the line 14 : 'else' without a previous 'if' but I could not find out what the error is.  What should I change the code??

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

enum ttt {X, O, UNMARKED};
enum ttt board[3][3];
enum evalboard{XWon, OWon, NoOneWon, NotOverYet};

void evaluation(void){
    int i;

    /*Check the rows*/
    for(i = 0; i < 3; i = i + 1){
        if( (board[i][0] == X) && (board[i][1] == X) && (board[i][2] == X) )
            evalboard = XWon; break;

        else if(board[i][0] == O && board[i][1] == O && board[i][0] == O )
            evalboard = OWon; break;

        else if(board[i][0] == UNMARKED || board[i][1] == UNMARKED || board[i][2] == UNMARKED )
            evalboard = NotOverYet; break;

        else if(board[i][0] != UNMARKED || board[i][1] != UNMARKED || board[i][2] != UNMARKED )
            evalboard = NoOneWon; break;
    }

    /*Check the columns*/
    for(i = 0; i < 3; i = i + 1){
        if( board[0][i] == X && board[1][i] == X && board[0][i] == X )
            evalboard XWon; break;

        else if( board[0][i] == O && board[1][i] == O && board[0][i] == O) )
            evalboard OWon; break;

        else if(board[0][i] == UNMARKED || board[1][i] == UNMARKED || board[2][i] == UNMARKED )
            evalboard = NotOverYet; break;

        else if(board[i][0] != UNMARKED || board[i][1] != UNMARKED || board[i][2] != UNMARKED )
            evalboard = NoOneWon; break;
    }

    /*Check the diagonals*/

    else if( board[0][0] == X && board[1][1] == X && board[0][0] == X )
        evalboard XWon;

    else if( board[0][2] == O && board[1][1] == O && board[0][2] == O )
        evalboard OWon;
}
```

Comment: I don't work with whatever language this is but I'd suggest looking at the last few lines (beneath `/*Check the diagonals*/`). Try changing the first to `if( board[0][0] == X && board[1][1] == X && board[0][0] == X )`

Comment: You need curled braces ( '{' and '}' ) around the body of your if/else if/else.

Comment: `goto fail; goto fail;` XD ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add braces.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

enum ttt {X, O, UNMARKED};
enum ttt board[3][3];
enum evalboard{XWon, OWon, NoOneWon, NotOverYet};

void evaluation(void){
    int i;

    /*Check the rows*/
    for(i = 0; i < 3; i = i + 1){
        if( (board[i][0] == X) && (board[i][1] == X) && (board[i][2] == X) )
        {
            evalboard = XWon;
            break;
        }
        else if(board[i][0] == O && board[i][1] == O && board[i][0] == O )
        {
            evalboard = OWon;
            break;
        }
        else if(board[i][0] == UNMARKED || board[i][1] == UNMARKED || board[i][2] == UNMARKED )
        {
            evalboard = NotOverYet;
            break;
        }
        else if(board[i][0] != UNMARKED || board[i][1] != UNMARKED || board[i][2] != UNMARKED )
        {
            evalboard = NoOneWon;
            break;
        }
    }

    /*Check the columns*/
    for(i = 0; i < 3; i = i + 1){
        if( board[0][i] == X && board[1][i] == X && board[0][i] == X )
        {
            evalboard XWon;
            break;
        }
        else if( board[0][i] == O && board[1][i] == O && board[0][i] == O) )
        {
            evalboard OWon;
            break;
        }
        else if(board[0][i] == UNMARKED || board[1][i] == UNMARKED || board[2][i] == UNMARKED )
        {
            evalboard = NotOverYet;
            break;
        }
        else if(board[i][0] != UNMARKED || board[i][1] != UNMARKED || board[i][2] != UNMARKED )
        {
            evalboard = NoOneWon;
            break;
        }
    }

    /*Check the diagonals*/

    else if( board[0][0] == X && board[1][1] == X && board[0][0] == X )
        evalboard XWon;

    else if( board[0][2] == O && board[1][1] == O && board[0][2] == O )
        evalboard OWon;
}
```

That is because you have more than 1 instruction in your conditionnal block. It is not like a switch ;)